# How do I create shipments at the time an order is created through the Spree API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I have an application that integrates with the Spree API. In the default flow of the Spree API, the shipments are created when an order transitions to delivery as per line 90 from *core.app.models.spree.order.checkout.rb*:

```
before_transition :to => :delivery, :do => :create_proposed_shipments
```

Because I am specifying both the line items and the shipping address during my initial post to create the order, I want Spree to create the shipments too.

So far I created an *orders_controller_decorator* where I overrode the *create* method with the original create code plus a call to *create_proposed_shipments*, but I am getting *NameError (uninitialized constant Order)* from the code I copied from the original *create* method.

My current *orders_controller_decorator*:

```
Spree::Api::OrdersController.class_eval do

  def create
    authorize! :create, Order
    @order = Spree::Core::Importer::Order.import(current_api_user, order_params)
    @order.create_proposed_shipments
    respond_with(@order, default_template: :show, status: 201)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the right idea. Once I fixed the NameError related to Order by specifying the module, everything worked as expected.

```
module Spree
  Api::OrdersController.class_eval do

    def create
      authorize! :create, Order
      @order = Core::Importer::Order.import(current_api_user, order_params)
      @order.create_proposed_shipments
      respond_with(@order, default_template: :show, status: 201)
    end

  end
end
```

alternatively, I could have done

```
Spree::Api::OrdersController.class_eval do

  def create
    authorize! :create, Spree::Order
    @order = Core::Importer::Order.import(current_api_user, order_params)
    @order.create_proposed_shipments
    respond_with(@order, default_template: :show, status: 201)
  end

end
```